# Android Espresso: Click on a view/recyclerview/list without id

Tags: android-espresso

I'm trying to click on the 1st item in the list/recyclerview but i don't know the element id/text for that view.

Is there anyway I can click the 1st item of the list/recyclerview view without giving element id